# How to get a specific parent of a path by its name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a function that returns the full path of a **specific** parent that I look for by a constant name. I am currently using `os.path` and strings for paths so right now this is done with regular-expressions.

What I want is for example for a constant `parent = d` to be able to get:

```
/a/b/c/d/e      -->  /a/b/c/d
/a/b/c/d/e/f    -->  /a/b/c/d
/root/a/b/c/d/e -->  /root/a/b/c/d
```

*Note*: as the example shows I don't want to rely on any fixed position from both sides.

I have tried 2 ways but both feels a bit clunky:

1. Use the [`parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) in order to find the correct [`parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) element:

   ```
   >>> path = "/a/b/c/d/e/f"
   >>> parts = Path(path).parts
   >>> parent_index = len(parts) - 1 - parts.index('d') - 1
   >>> Path(path).parents[parent_index]
   PosixPath('/a/b/c/d')
   ```
2. Use the [`parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) and concatenate the relevant ones:

   ```
   >>> path = "/root/a/b/c/d/e"
   >>> parts = Path(path).parts
   >>> Path(*parts[:parts.index('d')+1])
   PosixPath('/root/a/b/c/d')
   ```

I would say that the second one seems reasonable, but still, my question is: Is there a more direct, *pythonic* way to achieve this? The repeated indexing and slicing of the `parents` feels inefficient and quite confusing.

---

P.S. In case the part is not present in the path it is enough to raise an exception or any indicator (right now I wrap the code with `index` above with a `try/except`).

Comment: `os.path.dirname(mypath)`

Comment: @Todd `os.path.dirname("/a/b/c/d/e/f")` will give `'/a/b/c/d/e'` but I am looking for `'/a/b/c/d'` as stated in the example above

Comment: call os.path.dirname() again =)

Comment: If your application is trying to get a listing of all the file paths that terminate in 'd', you might be able to use `glob.glob('**/d', recursive=True)` - but don't do this from root because it'll take forever. You'd probably want to constrain that to specific folder trees.

Comment: @Todd again, as you can see in the examples, the number of parents varies. As to the `glob`, this will bring up many results from the system and I only need the one in the given file's path

Comment: `**` tells glob that the nesting structure can vary, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop instead to keep searching backwards for a parent of the given name:

```
path = Path("/a/b/c/d/e/f")
while path.name != 'd':
    path = path.parent
    assert path.name, 'No parent found with the given name'
print(path)
```

This outputs:

```
/a/b/c/d
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, that does indeed convey the idea of searching backward in a readable way, and might be more efficient then the `parts` approach as there are now extra lists created and no slicing. I just might use that in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can split and join your string and use index of item +1

```
path='/a/b/c/d/e/f'
lpath=path.split('/')
index=lpath.index('d')+1
'/'.join(lpath[0:index])
```

output:

```
'/a/b/c/d'
```

Comment: Hi @Willian and thanks for your answer! I didn' state it explicitly in the question, but I would prefer if the code would be portable and not use string methods